# Reemplazar parte de la url en enlace href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy buscando un recurso de Jquery o Javascript para cambiar un enlace definido por otro, pero solo cambiar una parte de ese enlace:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/">Enlace</a>
```

Lo que busco es cambiar `https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/` por la **url actual del sitio** desde donde se visita. El nuevo enlace tendría como destino: `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/383026/`

**Nota:**
Sé, que por norma de la comunidad, debería ingresar parte del código JS para saber qué está mal y me ayuden, pues solo pude encontrar un código que reemplaza todo el href y colocar algo que no está funcionando solo generaría ruido en nuestra conversación. Solo sé que window.location.href puede ayudarme a obtener al url actual del sitio, pero no encuentro el modo de utilizarlo en el JS y reconstruir la url.

Espero se comprenda mi pregunta y me puedan ayudar. Les agradezco.

Comment: Segun reglamiento del sitio primero debes mostrar aquello que haz intentado (leer [ask]), por ahora si dices que eso es lo que haz intentado entonces no es valido, debes dar mas detalles acerca de que codigo haz intentado, con que problemas te haz encontrado etc.

Comment: Podrías aclarar tu pregunta por favor?

Comment: Para obtener el origen usa [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te etendí bien, esto es lo que estás buscando:

Solución utilizando **jQuery**:

```js
$("#btnCambiarURL").click(function() {
   
    var urlOriginal = $("#lnkPrueba").attr("href");
    
    //Se obtiene el inicio del segundo URL, buscando "http"
    var posSegundoUrl = urlOriginal.indexOf("http", 4)
    
    //Se obtiene el primer URL
    var primerUrl = urlOriginal.substring(0, posSegundoUrl);
    
    //Se obtiene el segundo URL
    var segundoUrl = urlOriginal.substring(posSegundoUrl);
    
    //Se define un URL nuevo
    var urlNuevo = "http://www.amazon.com.mx";
    
    $("#lnkPrueba").attr("href", primerUrl + urlNuevo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="lnkPrueba" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/">Enlace</a>
<br><br>
<button id="btnCambiarURL">Cambiar Link</button>
```

Solución utilizando **JavaScript**:

```js
function cambiarURL() {
       
      var urlOriginal = document.getElementById("lnkPrueba").href;

      //Se obtiene el inicio del segundo URL, buscando "http"
      var posSegundoUrl = urlOriginal.indexOf("http", 4)

      //Se obtiene el primer URL
      var primerUrl = urlOriginal.substring(0, posSegundoUrl);

      //Se obtiene el segundo URL
      var segundoUrl = urlOriginal.substring(posSegundoUrl);

      //Se define un URL nuevo
      var urlNuevo = "http://www.amazon.com.mx";

      document.getElementById("lnkPrueba").setAttribute("href", primerUrl + urlNuevo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="lnkPrueba" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/">Enlace</a>
<br><br>
<button onClick="cambiarURL()">Cambiar Link</button>
```

Solución afectando a varios elementos anchor (<a>):

```js
function cambiarURLs() {
       
      //Se obtiene el URL actual
      var urlActual = window.location.href;
      
      //Se obtienen todos los enlaces y se crea un arreglo con ellos en la variable "enlaces"
      var enlaces = document.getElementsByName("enlace");
      
      for(var enlace of enlaces) {
      
         var urlOriginal = enlace.getAttribute("href");
      
         //Se reemplaza la palabra "reemplaz" con el urlActual
         var urlNuevo = urlOriginal.replace("reemplaz", urlActual);
      
         enlace.setAttribute("href", urlNuevo);
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a name="enlace" href="https://www.google.com/reemplaz">Enlace 1</a>
<br><br>
<a name="enlace" href="https://hotmail.com/reemplaz">Enlace 2</a>
<br><br>
<a name="enlace" href="https://yahoo.com/reemplaz">Enlace 3</a>
<br><br>
<a name="enlace" href="https://amazon.com/reemplaz">Enlace 4</a>
<br><br>
<button onClick="cambiarURLs()">Cambiar Enlaces</button>
```

Comment: Es una buena idea a mi problema @Sagnalrac . La url principal no tiene que ser fija, lo que intento es que esta pueda variar según la url original del href del enlace. ¿Podrías ver la siguiente respuesta? Ahí modificaré y trataré de ser explícita con el código, en base a lo que nos propusiste.

Comment: Amigo @Sagnalrac, me enlíe. La solución que planteas me ayudó en todos los enlaces que tienen el mismo name="enlace" y misma urlOriginal (href="https://google.com/reemplaz") Vi que no todos tendrán la urlOriginal. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que aplique a todas los anchor que tienen **reemplaz** ? `href="https://hotmail.com/reemplaz"` , `href="https://yahoo.com/reemplaz"`  , `href="https://amazon.com/reemplaz"` , etc, y buscar cambiar **reemplaz** por urlActual y obtener como resultado hotmail.com/https://es.stackove... yahoo.com/https://es.stackove... amazon.com/https://es.stackove... entre otros.

Comment: No te preocupes si ya no tienes tiempo para responder, solo es una variante que no lo había planteado antes. Y agradecerte si te das algo de tiempo para responder a esta variante impensada. Estaré atenta, saludos. :)

Comment: Tenías que haber "jugado" un poco mas con el ciclo **for...of**. He editado mi respuesta, y le incluí mas comentarios, por si gustas revisarla. ;)

Comment: Por cierto, si temes "experimentar" con tu propio sitio, me gustaría recomendarte  este sitio web: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)** para que puedas proba/experimentar todo lo que se te ocurra **antes** de implementarlo en tu propio sitio! ;)

Comment: Amigo @Sagnalrac, te luciste en todas las respuestas. Lo digo porque todas son aplicables y la última sencillamente resuelve mi problema. Un gran aporte, ya que no encontré formas de solucionarlo en otros sitios. Te mando un abrazote.

Answer (score 0):

Opté por la opción Javascript e hice esta adaptación para llegar a la idea.¡Funciona! lo que necesito saber es si el código está en orden.

```js
var urlOriginal = document.getElementById("lnkPrueba").href;
var primerUrl = urlOriginal;
document.getElementById("lnkPrueba").setAttribute("href", primerUrl + window.location.href);
```

```html
<a id="lnkPrueba" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A">Enlace</a>
```

**Nota:**
Lo que hace es tomar la url original de href y añadirle la url actual del sitio.

Comment: Otra duda que tengo, @Sagnalrac, es si podemos prescindir de la librería de Jquery para llevar adelante esta acción.

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede. He actualizado mi respuesta por si gustas revisarla :)

Comment: Amigo @Sagnalrac, por fin obtuve el resultado deseado. Tus opciones me inspiraron mucho, solo quisiera saber si el código está en orden. Observé que con Javascript puedo prescindir de la librería de Jquery. ¿Es recomendable obviarla?

Comment: Acabo de ver tu edición y estoy confundido porque, según tu ejemplo original, el elemento anchor (<a>) ya traía 2 urls concatenados desde el inicio. Pero si no es así, entonces tu código te funcionará.

Comment: Contestando a tu pregunta, no encontraba una razón de peso para recomendarte dejar de usar **jQuery**, por lo que me puse a investigar y encontré esta pagina web que probablemente te de razones para ello: **[Por qué debes dejar de usar jQuery](https://platzi.com/blog/debes-dejar-de-usar-jquery/)**. Sin embargo, también recomiendo leer los comentarios, por ejemplo como este: *"Se debe aprender JQuery ya que el 74% de la Web lo utiliza, ofreciendo una gran cantidad de oportunidades laborales en soporte y mantenimiento."*.

Comment: Yo soy defensor de **jQuery**, en primer lugar, porque yo lo utilizo demasiado en mis trabajos. En segundo, porque como lo leerás en los comentarios, con **jQuery** generalmente utilzas menos líneas para realizar una tarea que en **JavaScript** (vainilla). Y en tercero, y para mi el **mas importante**, la cantidad de plugins **gratuitos** que puedes encontrar en la web ya listos para ser utilizados en tu sitio web. En el siguiente comentario te comparto los que mas he utilizado, y sigo utilizando a la fecha, en mis trabajos:

Comment: 1) **[jQuery DataTable](https://datatables.net/)**, mi favorito. No me imagino trabajar sin él. 2) **[jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)**, bastante **útil** para validar tus formularios desde el cliente. 3) **[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)**, de aquí utilizo principalmente el **Date Picker**. 4) **[Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)**, lo acabo de conocer y me enamoré de él. 5) **[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)**, super útil para manipular fechas.6) **[Chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**. 7) **[jQuery Block UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)**

Comment: Mi recomendación final sería que, en lo que se refiere a **manipulación del DOM** y a **realizar peticiones Ajax** aprendas como hacerlo de ambas maneras, es decir, tanto con **jQuery** como con **JavaScript**. Ah, por cierto, si no es mucha molestia, si consideraste mi respuesta útil, la podrías marcar como respuesta por favor? Gracias y saludos! :)

Comment: Tengo varios elementos anchor con una url original y "diferente". A la url original quise concatenar la segunda, es decir, urlOriginal + urlActualdelsitio. Por eso en el ejemplo concatené una segunda url para ver como reemplazar esa segunda. La intención siempre fue solo reemplazar ese elemento (2da Url) con la url actual del sitio.

Comment: En las respuestas que me enviaste, solo vi la forma de tratar una id y bueno, yo tengo la intención de que se aplique en varias class, por tener varios elementos anchor que tratar. En mi pregunta incial ¿Cómo reemplazar una parte de la url? debería haber colocado esta referencia `href="https://google.com/reemplaz"` y buscar cambiar **reemplaz** por urlActual y como resultado obtener https://google.com/https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/...

Comment: @Sagnalrac esa base de conocimientos me resulta útil, estoy agradecida. ¿Por qué trato de obviar la librería de Jquery? Estoy trabajando en un sitio personal que sea fácil de cargar y por eso mis intenciones de reducir todo peso y cargas externas de url's en las librerías. Por decisión propia voy escatimando recursos al máximo para que sea lo más veloz. Ya tuve experiencia en cargar de todo y lograr no entender nada al final utilizando cosas que ni sabía de lo que hacía.

Comment: Claro que daré por resuelto el asunto, @Sagnalrac, ya que te diste el tiempo para ayudar a está anónima joven aprendiz. Aunque no supe cómo explicarme, pero fuiste el único que trató de entenderme. Investigaré más y espero pronto lograr cambiar todos los **reemplaz** por la urlActual del sitio. Saludos. :)

Comment: Vaya! Parece que por fin entendí lo que querías originalmente (o al menos eso espero). He vuelto a editar mi respuesta incluyendo una 3ra solución (utilizando JavaScript), en la que reemplazo 3 links simultáneamente y solo una parte de su url original por la url del sitio actual. La podrías revisar por favor y decirme si era eso lo que estabas buscando?

Comment: **Solucionado** Vaya, por fin doy con la respuesta. ¡Funciona! :) Ahora solo estudiar y aprender de todo lo que me expusiste, @Sagnalrac. Te mando un abrazote y espero poder conversar contigo en otra duda, cuando la tenga. Fuiste de mucha ayuda para mí y la comunidad.